# How to append a list to a dictionary using a loop

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to add several lists to one dictionary but it looks like it is printing the last entry from the loop. Any ideas how can I avoid it?

```
list_orbited_planet = ["Earth", "Mars", "Pluto", "Uranus"]
low = ["Earth", "Mars", "Mars", "Uranus"]
high = ["Pluto", "Pluto", "Uranus"]
entities = {'low': low, 'high': high}
listPlanets = []

for i in range(len(list_orbited_planet)):
  entities['low'] = low.count(list_orbited_planet[i])
  entities['high'] = high.count(list_orbited_planet[i])
  orbited_planet = {list_orbited_planet[i]: entities}
  print(orbited_planet)
  listPlanets.append(orbited_planet)

print(listPlanets)
```

I want my output to be like this:

```
[{'Earth': {'low': 1, 'high': 0}}, {'Mars': {'low': 2, 'high': 0}}, {'Pluto': {'low': 0, 'high': 2}}, {'Uranus': {'low': 1, 'high': 1}}]
```

However, it only displays Uranus value in every value so it is literaly low = 1, high = 1 everywhere.

Comment: Wow, it was my first post on this website and I didn't expect so many answers in such a short amount of time, thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to go a little further than the previous answers, with a few advices:

1. Why using a `for i in range` loop when you could simply do `for planet in planets`? (much more readable)
2. You're defining too much variable s in this loop without any need, that will just bring confusion. Every variable should represent some logical entity.
3. You need to define a new dictionnary at each iteration, otherwise the previously defined will just be updated each time.

This could give you something like that:

```
list_orbited_planet = ["Earth", "Mars", "Pluto", "Uranus"]
low = ["Earth", "Mars", "Mars", "Uranus"]
high = ["Pluto", "Pluto", "Uranus"]

listPlanets = []

for planet in list_orbited_planet:
    orbited_planet = {
        planet:
        {
            'low': low.count(planet),
            'high': high.count(planet)
        }
    }
    listPlanets.append(orbited_planet)

print(listPlanets)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary dictionary in the loop, like this:

```py
list_orbited_planet = ["Earth", "Mars", "Pluto", "Uranus"]
low = ["Earth", "Mars", "Mars", "Uranus"]
high = ["Pluto", "Pluto", "Uranus"]
entities = {'low': low, 'high': high}
listPlanets = []

for i in range(len(list_orbited_planet)):
    tmp_entities = {}
    tmp_entities['low'] = low.count(list_orbited_planet[i])
    tmp_entities['high'] = high.count(list_orbited_planet[i])
    orbited_planet = {list_orbited_planet[i]: tmp_entities}
    listPlanets.append(orbited_planet)

print(listPlanets)
```

which gives the following output:

```
[{'Earth': {'low': 1, 'high': 0}}, {'Mars': {'low': 2, 'high': 0}}, {'Pluto': {'low': 0, 'high': 2}}, {'Uranus': {'low': 1, 'high': 1}}]
```

If `entities` is not needed anywhere else, you can also remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_orbited_planet = ["Earth", "Mars", "Pluto", "Uranus"]
low = ["Earth", "Mars", "Mars", "Uranus"]
high = ["Pluto", "Pluto", "Uranus"]
entities = {'low': low, 'high': high}
listPlanets = []

for i in range(len(list_orbited_planet)):
  newEntities = dict()
  newEntities['low'] = low.count(list_orbited_planet[i])
  newEntities['high'] = high.count(list_orbited_planet[i])
  orbited_planet = {list_orbited_planet[i]: newEntities}
  print(orbited_planet)
  listPlanets.append(orbited_planet)

print(listPlanets)
```

Since your `entities` is being referenced for every loop, they are actually manipulating the same variable that is stored in the same address. Therefore, simply declare a new variable to avoid that behaviour.

output:

```
{'Earth': {'low': 1, 'high': 0}}
{'Mars': {'low': 2, 'high': 0}}
{'Pluto': {'low': 0, 'high': 2}}
{'Uranus': {'low': 1, 'high': 1}}
[{'Earth': {'low': 1, 'high': 0}}, {'Mars': {'low': 2, 'high': 0}}, {'Pluto': {'low': 0, 'high': 2}}, {'Uranus': {'low': 1, 'high': 1}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `orbited_planet = {list_orbited_planet[i]: entities}` always uses the exact same dictionary `entities` for every planet. This means that every planet shared the same dictionary, whose values were last set in the final pass through the loop. One solution is to change that line to

```
orbited_planet = {list_orbited_planet[i]: entities.copy()}
```

and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have a little error in your foor loop. Try this more readable way:

```
for planet  in list_orbited_planet:
    entities = {'low': low.count(planet), 'high':high.count(planet)}
    listPlanets.append({planet: entities})

print(listPlanets)
Output: [{'Earth': {'low': 1, 'high': 0}}, {'Mars': {'low': 2, 'high': 0}}, {'Pluto': {'low': 0, 'high': 2}}, {'Uranus': {'low': 1, 'high': 1}}]
```